# go verify module failed (how does go sumsdb work?)

Tags: go, go-modules

I encountered this error on `go build`:

```
go: github.com/frankban/quicktest@v1.14.2: verifying module: github.com/frankban/quicktest@v1.14.2: Get "https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/frankban/quicktest@v1.14.2": Not Found
```

My question is, why the `frankban/quicktest` is not found in sum db? as a matter of fact this is not the only package that caused this error, last time I try to compile the same project (about an hour ago), the error was on `golang.org/x/xerrors`.

Further more, could anyone explain (or point out some documents/articles/blogs) on how the go module system's "sums db" work.   It is very frustrating if anyone encounter such error as there seems nothing you can do to fix it?

Full log:

```
$ go get -u
go: downloading github.com/tealeg/xlsx v1.0.5
go: downloading github.com/shabbyrobe/xmlwriter v0.0.0-20220218224045-defe0ad214f6
go: downloading github.com/frankban/quicktest v1.14.2
go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.3.3
go: downloading github.com/google/btree v1.0.1
go: downloading github.com/kr/pretty v0.3.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20191204190536-9bdfabe68543
go: downloading github.com/kr/text v0.2.0
go: github.com/frankban/quicktest@v1.14.2: verifying module: github.com/frankban/quicktest@v1.14.2: Get "https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/frankban/quicktest@v1.14.2": Not Found
go: github.com/google/btree@v1.0.1: verifying module: github.com/google/btree@v1.0.1: Get "https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/google/btree@v1.0.1": Not Found
go: github.com/kr/pretty@v0.3.0: verifying module: github.com/kr/pretty@v0.3.0: Get "https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/kr/pretty@v0.3.0": Not Found
go: github.com/kr/text@v0.2.0: verifying module: github.com/kr/text@v0.2.0: Get "https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/kr/text@v0.2.0": Not Found
go: github.com/shabbyrobe/xmlwriter@v0.0.0-20220218224045-defe0ad214f6: verifying module: github.com/shabbyrobe/xmlwriter@v0.0.0-20220218224045-defe0ad214f6: Get "https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/shabbyrobe/xmlwriter@v0.0.0-20220218224045-defe0ad214f6": Not Found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sum.golang.org` server needs some time to update the hash sum. Try again now. Everything works correctly for me:

```
$ GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/shabbyrobe/xmlwriter@v0.0.0-20220218224045-defe0ad214f6
go: downloading github.com/shabbyrobe/xmlwriter v0.0.0-20220218224045-defe0ad214f6
go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.3.2
```

```
$ curl https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/shabbyrobe/xmlwriter@v0.0.0-20220218224045-defe0ad214f6
9249991
github.com/shabbyrobe/xmlwriter v0.0.0-20220218224045-defe0ad214f6 h1:ri617veNyNwEMXywzcLmU//YIVSFdJvdk39lNsFB/Ro=
github.com/shabbyrobe/xmlwriter v0.0.0-20220218224045-defe0ad214f6/go.mod h1:tKYSeHyJGYz7eoZMlzrRDQSfdYPYt0UduMr8b97Mmaw=

go.sum database tree
9690070
OufFSNsOUYeDJ2VPyrxBAe7/d47lQYkE03JZL2ltaI8=

— sum.golang.org Az3grkvrWUkW3Rvnl5QL72oZpiY5ifJhab3/evZCb0hmRkEtGRE/tCMyFDXftZWFi2SF71EuHAxJMTgLd1laHabOzAE=
```

Comment: does that mean when this kind of error happens, the only thing a developer can do is **wait**?

Comment: If you want to do everything without too much hassle, you just have to wait. But if you don't want to wait, you can read about 1) `GO111MODULE` environment variable 2) or `replace` in the `go.mod` file.

Comment: @xrfang you can try `GOSUMDB=off go get download` or `GOSUMDB=off go get ...` and it will not check to verify the checksum